# Class of std::vector vs non-member functions (along with a typedef)

Tags: c++, class, oop, vector

I have the following design dilemma in my project:
I have objects of a class I've designed stored within a `std::vector`.
I would like to add some methods for this kind of vector (`std::vector<MyClass>`).
I'm thinking of encapsulating this vector in another class and add these methods which I need and of course provide all the functionality of `std::vector` which I use. Is this a wise idea? or should I just use non-member functions and maybe a `typedef` for my own convenient?

Comment: Why not write non-member functions?

Comment: I do not get in which way `typedef` will help you?

Comment: @juanchopanza, that's the second option. Non-member functions will force me to send the `std::vector` as a parameter to them, which I prefer not to do all the time.

Comment: @PiotrNycz, it's just for use a shorter name than `std::vector<MyClass>`

Comment: It seems like the simplest option.

Comment: @juanchopanza, yes, but not much an object orientated approach.

Comment: Who cares? Object orientation should make life easier, not more complicated.

Comment: In C++, non-member functions in namespaces associated with a class `X` and taking `X` as a parameter are normally considered to be part of the public interface of class `X` (thanks to ADL). Using `.` is not necessary for a design to be object oriented.

Comment: And a design does not have to be object oriented to be good.

Comment: @ZachiShtain I understand the usage of `typedef`  - but I do not get in which way it will help in extending its interface?

Comment: Instead binding functions to the data, you can try binding functions to configuration of the operation to make functors. I guess your vector carries data, and are created dynamically. In this case, if configuration changes, you need to inform all instances about the change, assuming you don't want to make the configuration static. It'll be much easier to use new configurations to make new functors and pass them to the caller.

Comment: @PiotrNycz, the `typedef` won't extend its interface. As I said, it's only for my own convenient. Nothing more than that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non-member functions are the right thing in this instance. See Scott Meyer's article on the topic [How Non-Member Functions Improve Encapsulation](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/how-non-member-functions-improve-encapsu/184401197).

Also, please do use `typedef std::vector<MyClass> someTypeName;` You don't want `std::vector<MyClass>` littered throughout your code. You want what the type *is* not how it's implemented. If you ever have to change the implementation to use a different container, you will be quite glad you used a typedef.

**ETA:** in comments I am reminded of `using` and its superiority to `typedef`.

```
using someTypeName = std::vector<MyClass>;
```

Comment: Please DO NOT use `typedef`, use `using` instead.

Comment: @vladon, could you give an example on how to use `using` instead of `typedef`?

Comment: @ZachiShtain `using MySuperType = std::vector<MyClass>;`

Comment: @vladon, don't just tell us not do it; please explain why (a link to an explanation is fine). Since it's fairly new, I forgot about using and it's advantages. using should be preferred.

Comment: @RobK `using` can be templatized, while `typedef` can not. Except for that, there no advantages. As of me, I prefer `using` because of its better readability (`using NewType = Some_old_type` is better than `typedef Some_old_type NewType;`).

Answer (score 1):

You should use typedef only if your type is really meant to be a vector. A typedef gives you very little control on how your own type behaves and what you can do with it.

If not, and if you want a proper long living design, then you should hide the implementation details:

- What if tomorrow you use another standard container like a list or a map ?
- What if your requirements evolve and you need some non standard structures like concurrent_vectors or even a database ?
- What if at insertion or other vetor operation, you decide to do some additional steps.

Two ways of doing it:

- having a vector member and publish only the methods that you really need (according to the principle of *composition rather than inheritance*)
- inheriting from the standard vector, but again, ONLY IF your type represents a vector structure, AND IF you're aware of the limitations (e.g absence of virtual destructor, etc..) and their consequences.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to have a custom container that provides both std::vector member functions and custom functions specific to that container?

IMO, the most adapted way in your case is to create your own type and encapsulate your vector:

```
class MyClass{};

class MyContainer {
  using size_type = std::vector<MyClass>::size_type;
public:
  MyContainer() = default;
  MyContainer(std::vector<MyClass> const& vec) : vec_(vec) {}
  size_type size() const noexcept;
  // other functions you want

private:
  std::vector<MyClass> vec_;
};
```

Other "bad" options are :

- Create non-member functions, but it is not adapted to OOP design
- Inherit from std::vector, but STL classes are not designed for
  inheritance

Hope it will help you.

Comment: To the contrary, Scott Myers makes a very good case that [non-member functions improve encapsulation](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/how-non-member-functions-improve-encapsu/184401197).